# Erro em sqlite3 foreign ou foreigin

Tags: sqlite3

Eu criei um banco de dados em `sqlite3` na versão 3.9.2 e tive problemas com a foreign key.

```
alter table table_01 add column tab_2 integer foreign key references table_02(id);
    // Esse deu erro de sintaxe no foreign key
    alter table table_01 add column tab_2 integer foreigin key references table_02(id);
    // Já esse, adicionou o campo com sucesso.
```

como está no código, o gdb aceitou **foreigin** ao invés de **foreign**, alguém poderia saberia me dizer algo sobre isso?

Comment: De uma olhada nesta documentação: [http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#foreign-key-clause](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#foreign-key-clause) me ajudou bastante a entender a syntax e aos limites do sqlite com ForeignKeys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade, ao passar `foreigin key`, se estiver usando Sqlitestudio, ele entende que você está passando o tipo, junto com o `integer`. Veja o print da mesma query que rodei aqui:

Query de inserção(idêntica a que você fez):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como ficou a coluna após inserção:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pode-se perceber que a coluna foi adicionada como `foreign key`, mas a sintaxe usada foi ignorada para este fim.

Como pode ser visto [nesta resposta do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23574053/5524514), a sintaxe correta para essa alteração é:

```
ALTER TABLE tabela ADD COLUMN coluna TIPO REFERENCES tabela_parente(coluna_parente);
```

Veja abaixo no print, a coluna adicionada em testes que fiz, executando o comando acima:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Referencias para leitura:**

**https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html**

**https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html#otheralter** (importante a leitura)